# How to use Weka Packages in R?

Tags: r, weka

I usually use RWeka library in R, to use Weka in R.
However, I think RWeka Only support Weka's default function.
Is there any method to use Weka's Package(like imageFilters, multiboostAB ) in R?

Comment: use the newest version of RWeka, and try the `WPM()` function (Weka Package Manager)

Comment: Thanks! your comment is really help to get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :)

Setting WEKA_HOME global variable as Users\'username'\wekafiles

and make model like this

```
Elastic <- make_Weka_classifier('weka/classifiers/functions/ElasticNet',
                              c('ElasticNet', 'Weka_functions'),
                              init = make_Weka_package_loader('elasticNet'))

LBR <- make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/lazy/LBR",
                         c('LBR', 'Weka_lazy'),
                         init=make_Weka_package_loader("lazyBayesianRules"))
```

Comment: Can you please advise on how to use rWeka for calculating ROC AUC?